# Chrome Rich Notifications for Extensions Only?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, notifications, google-chrome-app

I have a page that I would like to enhance by using Chrome's Rich Notifications. The pages I've read however, seem to imply that this API is only available to Chrome extensions. Is this the case? I would love to take advantage of the API, but I don't want to invest the time in converting my web application into a Chrome extension unless absolutely necessary.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *does seem* that without writing an extension *for* your webapp, or converting your webapp into a full (packaged) Chrome App, you cannot get access to `chrome.notifications`.

I've tried to make a [Hosted App](https://developers.google.com/chrome/apps/docs/developers_guide#live) with `"notifications"` permission in the manifest, but that only grants access to HTML5 `Notification` without asking the user. Same goes for background pages.

Your best bet is to make a minimalistic extension that your page [can communicate with](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage). Once that is published, you can advertise the extension to your users with [Inline Install](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/inline_installation).