# Chrome Rich Notifications - How to use it

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

For 2-3 days I'm trying to use Chrome rich notification. I've read some reviews regarding this but nobody tells how to use implement it.

1. I want to try it in a html test page. How can I do this? because I couldn't manage to show at least a basic notification... :(
2. I want to implement this in an extension that I'm building. How can I do this? There are special instructions?

I don't need this simple notification:

```
function notifyMe() {

      if (!("Notification" in window)) {
        alert("This browser does not support desktop notification");
      }

      else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
        var notification = new Notification("Message");
      }

      else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {
        Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {

          if(!('permission' in Notification)) {
            Notification.permission = permission;
          }

          if (permission === "granted") {
            var notification = new Notification("Message");
          }
        });
      }
    }//--Notification code--
```

I need rich notification because I need a bunch of options which this is offering.

Can someone help me with a tutorial or a html test page to understand how to implement it?

Comment: What you show here is NOT what is called [Rich Notifications](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/richNotifications) (that would be [`chrome.notifications` API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/notifications)). Here's it's just plain [web notification API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/notification).

Comment: I know what I showed here. This is why I said "I don't need this simple notification:" I need something to set the title, the body etc.

Comment: You should make that "don't" **bold**, I missed it the first time I read the question. It makes little sense to include such a complete example of what you **don't** need - just the name and a link to docs would be sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

1) You can't use most of `chrome` APIs outside extensions with proper permissions. So you cannot test it in a standalone HTML file - *unless* it's packed in an extension, i.e. an options page.

So you can add a `test.html` file to an extension's folder, and open it as

```
chrome-extension://yourExtensionIdHere/test.html
```

It might be easier to test it in the background script though.

2) Well, you need to read [the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/notifications)! There's also some examples in [this article](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/richNotifications).

Points to remember:

1. You need to declare the `"notifications"` permission.
2. You can't use them in a content script.
3. Icon is *required*.
4. <del>Callbacks (even doing nothing) are required</del> (this was a bug until Chrome 42).

   I highly recommend using a diagnostic callback:

   ```
   function diag() {
     if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
       console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
     }
   }

   chrome.notifications.create(id, options, diag);
   ```

   It will warn you of any errors while using the API.

Comment: Callbacks are probably [going to be optional](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=163750#c20) in Chrome 42.

Comment: @RobW I never doubted that after you self-assigned that bug ;)

Comment: I just want to know how can I implement this API with a web page then. I understood that I can't use it implemented as <script type="text/javascript"> in a basic html page. I just want to know what code should put in html page after I installed the Notification API Sample. Can you help me with this?

Comment: You _can't_ use it outside an extension. As sad as that is. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/24632983/934239 - if you want to add rich notifications to a website, you need to write an extension and ask your users to install it. Edit: better question is this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26621042/934239