# Uncaught ReferenceError: webkitNotifications is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app

I am new to Chrome app envelopment as well as to javascript and trying to build a notification feature in chrome app with the help of [this](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktop_notifications) doc.
Below is the cod of my js file

```
var app=new function(){

 var notification = webkitNotifications.createNotification(
  '128.png',  // icon url - can be relative
  'Hello!',  // notification title
  'Lorem ipsum...'  // notification body text
);
notification.show();  

};
```

But it gives me a "Uncaught ReferenceError: webkitNotifications is not defined" error at the second line. How should i define this webkitNotifications?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23288755/chrome-webkitnotification-not-found-api-missing

Answer (score 6):

You're using *massively* outdated documentation. It even has a big deprecation warning at the top.

`webkitNotifications` is no more; on the web, it's replaced by the [`Notifications` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API/Using_the_Notifications_API), but..

..since you're building a Chrome App, this is not the optimal route. You should be using the [`chrome.notifications` API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/notifications) as a more feature-rich, extension/app only API.

Docs contain a [more up to date tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/richNotifications) on that (still outdated though as the Notification Center is no more).

Comment: It's funny because that's the current documentation from Google. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktop_notifications

Comment: @Slick86 and it still has the deprecation warning on top.